# Avoid Public IP based browsing of website in Apache 2.4

Tags: security, apache-httpd, firewall, apache-virtualhost

We are hosting a website locally. For this purpose, we have a public IP and corresponding DNS entry. We are using Apache 2.4 web-server. The website is publicly accessible without any problem. But website can also be assessed by proving public IP.

How can I avoid IP based public access of my website ? Should I update Apache (virtual host) configuration or where it should be handled ?

I know how to restrict client (IP) in Apache but my case is totally different.

Update:
 Example, https://www.contoso.com/ should work but https://203.0.113.66/ should not. This is what I want

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me - that is indeed the question OP is asking.

Comment: The simple answer to the question is that you cannot prevent people from accessing your website via the IP address (for example I can access google by navigating to https://216.58.199.36, and I get redirected to google.com), however you can redirect them to the FQDN using [apache mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html) - simply use three lines inside the `VirtualHost` serving the website: (1): `RewriteEngine on`, (2): `RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" `, and (3): `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domainname.com/$1`

Comment: Isn't this the default situation? Do you actually have a certificate for `203.0.113.66`? Normally you need to actively do something to allow HTTPS connections to the IP address.

Comment: @AlexP the client can always ignore the certificate error. But I don't see what the OP's goal is. Nice experience for users? Some sort of misguided anti-hacking step? OP: why do you need this?

Comment: If the name and address of your site is known, nothing prevents anyone to add its address to their `/etc/hosts` file (or equivalent) and access it by name even if its name isn't in any public DNS. Not speaking of forging the `Host` header in requests with suitable utilities.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a default vhost in your apache configuration.
After that, define a vhost with the ServerName of the DNS name on which you want your website to be found.

Now requests with that name in the Host header will be handled by that vhost, and any other requests (with wrong or no hostname) will be handled by the default vhost (which should probably just be a page stating that a wrong host has been used, or similar).

If SSL (https) is being used, then requests to the IP address will get an SSL error anyway as the hostname (IP address in this case) does not match the hostname in the SSL certificate.

Answer (score 1):

*Using Ubuntu 18.04, Apache 2.4.29.*

I think that there is a default vHost in apache2 i.e `000-default.conf`. If your site is accessible through IP, you may have disabled this default configuration.

**A work-around:**

Edit `000-default.conf` and put a redirect there.

`nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

In `000-default.conf`

`<VirtualHost *:80>
Redirect / https://www.contoso.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
Redirect / https://www.contoso.com/
</VirtualHost>`

Enable the configuration, if needed.

`a2ensite 000-default.conf`

Reload Apache2.

`systemctl reload apache2.service`

Hope it helps.